# cannot serialize XML for more than once using using OAI-PMH protocol

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, oai

I want to get `XML` format data using `OAI-PMH` protocol. when I deserialize `XML` for the fisrt time using `XmlSerializer`, there is no problem, but when I try to get url content by a `resumption token`, I got the below error when trying to deserialize `XML`, eventhough the `xmlreader` correctly reads content:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Xml.dll
>
> Additional information: There is an error in XML document (149, 26).
>
> InnerException:Value was either too large or too small for an unsigned byte.

the code is like this:

```
//getting content for the first time
string urlContent = BaseCommons.HttpHandler.getContent(first-time-url-link);
StreamReader OAIStream = new StreamReader(new MemoryStream(
                                          Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(urlContent)));
var reader = XmlReader.Create(
             OAIStream.BaseStream, new XmlReaderSettings() { 
             ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Document });
OAI.OAIPMH OAIRes = new XmlSerializer(typeof(OAI.OAIPMH)).Deserialize(
                    reader) as OAI.OAIPMH;
//getting content for more than once
while (OAIRes.ListRecords.resumptionToken.Value != null && 
       OAIRes.ListRecords.resumptionToken.Value.ToString() != "")
      {
       string nextUrl = BaseCommons.HttpHandler.getContent(second-url-with-resumption + 
                        OAIRes.ListRecords.resumptionToken.Value.ToString());
       StreamReader OAIStream1 = new StreamReader(
                                new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(nextUrl)));
       //xmlreader correctly reads content
       XmlReader reader1 = XmlReader.Create(OAIStream1.BaseStream, new XmlReaderSettings() { ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Document });
       // the error occured here 
       OAI.OAIPMH OAIRes1 = new XmlSerializer(typeof(OAI.OAIPMH)).Deserialize(reader1) as OAI.OAIPMH;
      }
```

According to [the Microsoft Exception explanation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/330592), I added a default `constructor` to my `OAIPMH partial class`, but the same error occurred.
the `OAI` class which is `xml` object class is like below:

```
  public class OAI{
            
            /// <remarks/>
            [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/")]
            [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute("OAI-PMH", Namespace="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/", IsNullable = false)]
          public partial class OAIPMH
           {

            private System.DateTime responseDateField;

            private OAIPMHRequest requestField;

            private OAIPMHListRecords listRecordsField;

            /// <remarks/>
            public OAIPMH() { }
            public System.DateTime responseDate
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.responseDateField;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.responseDateField = value;
                }
            }

            /// <remarks/>
            public OAIPMHRequest request
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.requestField;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.requestField = value;
                }
            }

            /// <remarks/>
            public OAIPMHListRecords ListRecords
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.listRecordsField;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.listRecordsField = value;
                }
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/")]
        public partial class OAIPMHRequest
        {

            private string verbField;

            private string metadataPrefixField;

            private System.DateTime fromField;

            private System.DateTime untilField;

            private string valueField;

            /// <remarks/>
            [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
            public string verb
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.verbField;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.verbField = value;
                }
            }

            /// <remarks/>
            [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
            public string metadataPrefix
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.metadataPrefixField;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.metadataPrefixField = value;
                }
            }

            /// <remarks/>
            [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(DataType = "date")]
            public System.DateTime from
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.fromField;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.fromField = value;
                }
            }

            /// <remarks/>
            [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(DataType = "date")]
            public System.DateTime until
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.untilField;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.untilField = value;
                }
            }

            /// <remarks/>
            [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()]
            public string Value
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.valueField;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.valueField = value;
                }
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/")]
        public partial class OAIPMHListRecords
        {

            private OAIPMHListRecordsRecord[] recordField;

            private OAIPMHListRecordsResumptionToken resumptionTokenField;

            /// <remarks/>
            [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("record")]
            public OAIPMHListRecordsRecord[] record
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.recordField;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.recordField = value;
                }
            }

            /// <remarks/>
            public OAIPMHListRecordsResumptionToken resumptionToken
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.resumptionTokenField;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.resumptionTokenField = value;
                }
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/")]
        public partial class OAIPMHListRecordsRecord
        {

            private OAIPMHListRecordsRecordHeader headerField;

            private OAIPMHListRecordsRecordMetadata metadataField;

            /// <remarks/>
            public OAIPMHListRecordsRecordHeader header
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.headerField;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.headerField = value;
                }
            }

            /// <remarks/>
            public OAIPMHListRecordsRecordMetadata metadata
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.metadataField;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.metadataField = value;
                }
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/")]
        public partial class OAIPMHListRecordsRecordHeader
        {

            private string identifierField;

            private System.DateTime datestampField;

            private string setSpecField;

            private string statusField;

            /// <remarks/>
            public string identifier
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.identifierField;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.identifierField = value;
                }
            }

            /// <remarks/>
            public System.DateTime datestamp
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.datestampField;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.datestampField = value;
                }
            }

            /// <remarks/>
            public string setSpec
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.setSpecField;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.setSpecField = value;
                }
            }

            /// <remarks/>
            [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
            public string status
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.statusField;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.statusField = value;
                }
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/")]
        public partial class OAIPMHListRecordsRecordMetadata
        {

            private mods modsField;

            /// <remarks/>
            [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace = "http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3")]
            public mods mods
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.modsField;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.modsField = value;
                }
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3")]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3", IsNullable = false)]
        public partial class mods
        {

            private modsTitleInfo titleInfoField;

            private modsName[] nameField;

            private string typeOfResourceField;

            private string genreField;

            private modsOriginInfo originInfoField;

            private modsLanguage languageField;

            private modsAbstract[] abstractField;

            private modsSubject subjectField;

            private modsRelatedItem relatedItemField;

            /// <remarks/>
            public modsTitleInfo titleInfo
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.titleInfoField;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.titleInfoField = value;
                }
            }

            /// <remarks/>
            [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("name")]
            public modsName[] name
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.nameField;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.nameField = value;
                }
            }

            /// <remarks/>
            public string typeOfResource
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.typeOfResourceField;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.typeOfResourceField = value;
                }
            }

            /// <remarks/>
            public string genre
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.genreField;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.genreField = value;
                }
            }

            /// <remarks/>
            public modsOriginInfo originInfo
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.originInfoField;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.originInfoField = value;
                }
            }

            /// <remarks/>
            public modsLanguage language
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.languageField;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.languageField = value;
                }
            }

            /// <remarks/>
            [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("abstract")]
            public modsAbstract[] @abstract
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.abstractField;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.abstractField = value;
                }
            }

            /// <remarks/>
            public modsSubject subject
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.subjectField;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.subjectField = value;
                }
            }

            /// <remarks/>
            public modsRelatedItem relatedItem
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.relatedItemField;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.relatedItemField = value;
                }
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3")]
        public partial class modsTitleInfo
        {

            private string titleField;

            /// <remarks/>
            public string title
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.titleField;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.titleField = value;
                }
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3")]
        public partial class modsName
        {

            private string namePartField;

            private string typeField;

            /// <remarks/>
            public string namePart
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.namePartField;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.namePartField = value;
                }
            }

            /// <remarks/>
            [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
            public string type
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.typeField;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.typeField = value;
                }
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3")]
        public partial class modsOriginInfo
        {

            private string dateIssuedField;

            /// <remarks/>
            public string dateIssued
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.dateIssuedField;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.dateIssuedField = value;
                }
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3")]
        public partial class modsLanguage
        {

            private string languageTermField;

            /// <remarks/>
            public string languageTerm
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.languageTermField;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.languageTermField = value;
                }
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3")]
        public partial class modsAbstract
        {

            private string langField;

            private string typeField;

            private string valueField;

            /// <remarks/>
            [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Qualified, Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace")]
            public string lang
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.langField;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.langField = value;
                }
            }

            /// <remarks/>
            [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
            public string type
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.typeField;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.typeField = value;
                }
            }

            /// <remarks/>
            [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()]
            public string Value
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.valueField;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.valueField = value;
                }
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3")]
        public partial class modsSubject
        {

            private string topicField;

            private string geographicField;

            /// <remarks/>
            public string topic
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.topicField;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.topicField = value;
                }
            }

            /// <remarks/>
            public string geographic
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.geographicField;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.geographicField = value;
                }
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3")]
        public partial class modsRelatedItem
        {

            private modsRelatedItemTitleInfo titleInfoField;

            private modsRelatedItemPart partField;

            private string typeField;

            /// <remarks/>
            public modsRelatedItemTitleInfo titleInfo
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.titleInfoField;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.titleInfoField = value;
                }
            }

            /// <remarks/>
            public modsRelatedItemPart part
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.partField;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.partField = value;
                }
            }

            /// <remarks/>
            [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
            public string type
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.typeField;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.typeField = value;
                }
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3")]
        public partial class modsRelatedItemTitleInfo
        {

            private string titleField;

            /// <remarks/>
            public string title
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.titleField;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.titleField = value;
                }
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3")]
        public partial class modsRelatedItemPart
        {

            private modsRelatedItemPartDetail[] detailField;

            private string dateField;

            /// <remarks/>
            [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("detail")]
            public modsRelatedItemPartDetail[] detail
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.detailField;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.detailField = value;
                }
            }

            /// <remarks/>
            public string date
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.dateField;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.dateField = value;
                }
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3")]
        public partial class modsRelatedItemPartDetail
        {

            private byte numberField;

            private string captionField;

            private string typeField;

            /// <remarks/>
            public byte number
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.numberField;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.numberField = value;
                }
            }

            /// <remarks/>
            public string caption
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.captionField;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.captionField = value;
                }
            }

            /// <remarks/>
            [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
            public string type
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.typeField;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.typeField = value;
                }
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/")]
        public partial class OAIPMHListRecordsResumptionToken
        {

            private System.DateTime expirationDateField;

            private ushort completeListSizeField;

            private byte cursorField;

            private string valueField;

            /// <remarks/>
            [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
            public System.DateTime expirationDate
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.expirationDateField;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.expirationDateField = value;
                }
            }

            /// <remarks/>
            [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
            public ushort completeListSize
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.completeListSizeField;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.completeListSizeField = value;
                }
            }

            /// <remarks/>
            [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
            public byte cursor
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.cursorField;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.cursorField = value;
                }
            }

            /// <remarks/>
            [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()]
            public string Value
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.valueField;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.valueField = value;
                }
            }
        }
        
        }
```

how can I deserialize `xml` for more than once?

Comment: What is in the XML at row 149, column 26? XMLReader doesn't read the document through on creation so you can't say that it reads it correctly. Try creating an XMLDocument out of it and you should get the same error.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen there is no problem when using xDocument. and can get the total data!!!!!  the code is  `byte[] data;
                using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
                    data = webClient.DownloadData(url-link+ OAIRes.ListRecords.resumptionToken.Value.ToString());
                string str = Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8").GetString(data);
                XDocument xd = XDocument.Parse(str);`

Comment: I would compare the string nextUrl received the 1st time with the one received the 2nd time to see if both are valid xml.  To check if the xml is valid use the following VS menu : Project : Add New Item : XML File.  Then paste in the window the XML string nextUrl.  Any error will show up like any compiler errors in the Error List in VS.

Comment: @jdweng thanks I checked that and there where no problem with nextUrl content I think the problem is with OAI class!

Comment: You have 4 properties defined as 'byte'.  The number is the xml for one of these 4 values is larger than 256 or if negative < -128.  The easiest was of determining which of the 4 is the issue is to make them long values and see which one fixes the issue.

Comment: @jdweng thanks! that was correct the `number` property made the error